# Custom Component: Deferring events till after FormCreate

Tags: delphi, components

I have created a component that descends from a TTreeView and automatically filled with a specialized content. I have added my own OnSelectionChange event. OnSelectionChange is called from within the Change method (overriding the TTreeView.Change method ) when the handle has been allocated and ComponentState <> csReading or csLoading.

The problem is that when the component is added to a form the OnChange event occurs BEFORE FormCreate. How can I delay my events till after all creation has occurred?

I guess I could post a message to the component and react to that, but then I would only want to postmessage when in the state of creating. Is there a better way?

```
procedure TMyDescendentTreeView.Change(Node: TTreeNode);
begin
  inherited;

  if HandleAllocated and assigned( fOnSelChange) and (not ( csReading in ComponentState ))
    and (not ( csLoading in ComponentState )) then
    fOnSelChange( Self, TXYZ(Node).Data, TXYZ(Node) );
end;
```

Comment: Your component should not be using the OnChange event. That event is for the user of your component. You should be using `Change` instead, where you can do your test for csReading/csLoading, and then your handler can call the user's OnChange if it's assigned. See any Delphi VCL component for an example, using any of the TNotifyEvents (like TButton.Click, for instance).

Comment: Surely it would be possible to know exactly why/how the event handler is called before FormCreate if you posted code instead of describing it.

Comment: @Ken: Sorry, I should say that I don't use the OnChange event, my event is actually a custom OnSelChange and it is activated by my overriding the Change method.

Comment: @Sertec: To know when the selection changes i override the change event of the TTreeView, it triggers multiple times during creation

Comment: Don't describe it, you've already wasted a comment and an answer with vague descriptions.

Comment: *I don't use the OnChange* clashes with your post that says *I have written a custom OnChange*. Can you [edit] your post to make it clear what you're actually doing? Some code would also be helpful to clarify the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my post

Comment: So, what I am thinking is that in the Loaded method I will post a WM_Initialized to message my component. This will set a fIntialized property to true. When fIntialized =true the event will be allowed to fire...

Comment: OnChange is already called when a selection change occurs. What's the reason you're introducing a new event handler?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. A stock treeview's OnChange fires after OnCreate of the form that it's on.

Comment: @Zax note that `Loaded()` is called only for components that are streamed from a DFM. If the user creates your component dynamically in code instead, `Loaded()` will never be called, and your `fInitialized` won't get set to true.

Comment: @Sertac: Change occurs during creation because I fill it in the Loaded event. My control will contain special objects, so the OnSelChange event will return custom parameters, including a Typecast TTreeNode. Secondly, onSel[ection]Change is a better description of its function than OnChange.

Comment: @Remy: It is interesting to learn about Loaded. What alternative is available as the last event after creation?

Comment: @Zax "*What alternative is available as the last event after creation?*" - there isn't one, not inside the component, anyway. "*Change occurs during creation because I fill it in the Loaded event*" - so stop doing that. Again, by relying on `Loaded()`, users may miss out on your "special" inits for controls created in code. What does your custom component actually add that the standard `TTreeView` doesn't natively handle? Your `OnSelChange` should be fired whenever the standard `OnChange` is fired. Don't try to avoid that. Change what you are doing to make `OnChange` fire earlier then you want

Comment: @Remy: The component is a special kind of registry view, its default state is filled. Users do not fill it themselves. So it needs to be filled during creation (e.g. in CreateWnd). Rather than the user dealing with multiple OnSelectionChange events during creation (before they have even initialized their form) it makes sense for them to deal with a single event, once the component is filled to its default state and the form is ready.

Comment: You've been asked several times now to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, and you still have not done so. You're most likely not going to get help until you do, and the [help/on-topic] guidelines require that code in questions asking for debugging help.

Comment: If you are creating actual `TTreeNode` objects for the initial state, `CreateWnd()` is the wrong place to do that. Also, make sure you are using the TreeView's `(Begin|End)Update()` methods while filling the initial state. That may reduce how many times `Change()` is called. I might also suggest discarding [`TVN_SELCHANGED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/tvn-selchanged) notifications, or responding TRUE to [`TVN_SELCHANGING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/tvn-selchanging) notifications, while you are filling the initial state.

Comment: Thanks Remy, I improved the initialization code and also discard the change notifications while the component fills the treeview and that has resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so thanks to Remy Lebeau who helped me to understand my issue better. Because my component is filled with content by default, I discarded the change notifications that occurred during the initial fill (which happens once the handle is available).

So now the selection change event no longer occurs during component creation (and thus before FormCreate).

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't assign an `OnChange` handler to your component at design-time. Have the Form assign a handler dynamically in code from within its `OnCreate` event when it is ready:

```
procedure TMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //...

  MyTreeView1.OnChange := MyTreeView1Change;

  // optional, call the event now...
  MyTreeView1Change(MyTreeView1, MyTreeView1.Selected);

  //...
end;

procedure TMyForm.MyTreeView1Change(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode);
begin
  //...
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Remy, but that requires the user to know that my component operates in a unexpected way and needs to adjust their code to work around it

Comment: Then don't write your component to "operate in a unexpected way" to begin with.  What are you REALLY trying to solve? This is starting to sound like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/).

Comment: The custom treeview contains specialized content and is filled during creation. Users of the component will need to react to changes to the selected node using an OnSelectionChange. It would be terrible design if OnSelectionChange occurred on a form where form control and variable initialization had not even taken place.

Comment: @Zax "*is filled during creation*" - why?  What EXACTLY are you filling, and WHEN? "*It would be terrible design if OnSelectionChange occurred on a form where form control and variable initialization had not even taken place*" - and yet, Delphi's object design allows for that. Worse case, the user could override the Form's constructor to init the variables before calling the `inherited` constructor to invoke DFM streaming.

Comment: @Zax You shouldn't try to make your component smarter than it should be. If something changes in your component, and it already has a handler assigned that wants to be notified of changes, just call it. Let the handler deal with issues if delayed initializations as needed.